# Unable to install ros-humble-desktop on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS arm64

Tags: ros-humble

I already installed humble on this machine (Linux inu-arm-10 5.15.0-1030-raspi) a few months ago and everything went well, however today, after I had uninstalled humble and tried to reinstall it I am getting a lot of errors.
I had followed the installation commands from [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html) (just like I did before).
Looks like some of the links to the debians in the installation are broken, and noticed that those links were changed just recently.
For example, this link " [http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-humble-rosbag2/ros-humble-rosbag2_0.15.5-1jammy.20230428.164334_arm64.deb"](http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-humble-rosbag2/ros-humble-rosbag2_0.15.5-1jammy.20230428.164334_arm64.deb%22) can't be found, when I go to "http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-humble-rosbag2" I can see that "ros-humble-rosbag2_0.15.5-1jammy.20230428.164334_arm64.deb" doesn't exist and that the debians were just recently changed.

Any idea how can it be fixed?

Thanks,
Oded

[image]

Comment: Copy and paste the error into your question as text and not as a screenshot, as images are not text-searchable

Answer (score 2):

You likely need to do a "sudo apt-get update" - and pay attention to any errors that may be listed. This command will update your apt cache, which should fix the mismatched version numbers and build dates that you are seeing.

Comment: I already did it as part of the instructions I had followed from here: https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html when I update apt I am getting errors as well, for example: Reading package lists... Done
E: Release file for http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 196d 21h 33min 20s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.

Comment: These errors are what you need to debug - if apt cannot update the cache, you won't be able to install things. I would suggest updating your question with all of the errors from the apt update step.